# Transform of Hyperbolic PDE from Cartesian Coordinates into /theta and /Epsi coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

For the attached image

[image: Hyperbolic PDE]

I want to know how the transform is done for $u_{tt}-u_{xx}=0$ into $v_{\theta\psi}=0$ with $\theta=x+t$ and $\psi=x-t$. According to the image, the reference didn't state how the transform has been done for hyperbolic PDE into the final form of $v_{\theta\psi}=0$. I have revised chain rules used to transform these equations from cartesian into polar coordinates however this wasn't helpful either.

Comment: Please state, what you have already done, and what you are struggling at, so we know how to help you :)

Comment: According to the attached image, the reference didn't state how the transform has been done for hyperbolic PDE into the final form of V(theta,epsi)=0, I have revised chain rules used to transform these equations from cartesian into polar coordinates however this wasn't helpful either.

Comment: From $u(x,t)=v(\theta,\psi)$ and the chain rule, we know that \begin{aligned} u_t &= v_\theta\theta_t + v_\psi\psi_t \\ &= v_\theta - v_\psi \end{aligned} etc. (Proceed the same way for $u_{tt}=v_{\theta\theta} - 2v_{\psi\theta} + v_{\psi\psi}$, as well as $u_x = v_\theta + v_\psi$ and $u_{xx} = v_{\theta\theta} + 2v_{\psi\theta} + v_{\psi\psi}$ where the equality of mixed partials was used)

Comment: Thank you for clarification.
That is very helpfully really.